# GitHub Actions Badges for multiple jobs in a single file

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a single `deploy.yml` file with the following:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 Windows: ...
 Mac: ...
 Ubuntu: ...
```

Now if I create a badge pointing to the yml file I think it will give only one action passed.

1. Can I create 3 status badges (1 for each job)? Or do I need to split my workflow into 3 files (one job in each file)? And then report on them individually?
2. Can I have multiple badges? One shows `pull_request` build and one shows published release? But I guess if there are multiple PRs then I will have to specify which number/name or will it just pick the latest?

For 2nd query I think we can do published via `badge.svg?branch=main&event=release` but can we do something similar for `pull_request`? Any commits going into a branch is built and wanted to report on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, according to [Adding a workflow status badge](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge), you may use workflow filename, branch, and event to configure status badges.

> Can I create 3 Action badges (1 for each job)? Or do I need to split my yml into 3 deploy files have one job in each? And then report on them individually?

Yes, you have to split your workflow in multiple workflows to add different badge for each.

An improvement that you may have on this is by creating a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) for the common parts and then by calling that in your wrapper workflows per OS:

- main workflow - performing common sequence of operations
- wrapper workflow (Ubuntu) - calling main workflow
- wrapper workflow (macOS) - calling main workflow
- wrapper workflow (Winddows) - calling main workflow

> Can I have multiple badges? One shows `pull_request` build and one shows published release? But I guess if there are multiple PR's then I will have to specify which number / name or will it just pick the latest?

You may configure badges for `pull_request` event by using `branch` and `event` parameters. But, the granularity to choose by PR number is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem .. will try to split it.. haven't had success yet